# redis Geo distance (GEODIST) suspect not accurate

Tags: redis, geolocation

I am new to Redis and was trying GEODIST function but found the result was not consistent with the result i got from some website which provide geo distance calculation function.

for example,  i tried to points as

```html
GEOADD locations 35.0963009 -80.858142 "A" 35.145314 -80.842567 "B"
```

and

```html
GEODIST locations A B km
```

redis gave me 1.9370km but https://www.functions-online.com/geo-distance.html and https://www.geodatasource.com/distance-calculator
was giving me 5.37km

i then used google map to determine which one is more accurate and it turned out redis was wrong.

does anyone know the explanation and how to fix/adjust redis to give a more accurate result? like a ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out GEOADD takes lng, lat, name rather than lat, lng, name.
the first 2 arguments order was reversed.

Though I should read more carefully, the first sentence 'Adds the specified geospatial items (latitude, longitude, name) to the specified key. ' from doc https://redis.io/commands/geoadd was really confusing.